# Android calendar scheduller

Tags: android

Am new to android application and am using android studio for development.I need to develop a calendar scheduler with day and month view.Please suggest me any 3rd party plugin which i can use(ex:telerik) and should support day and month ![enter image description here][1]view with associated meeting or task in blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen these solutions: https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid and https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView?